# is the space in a function constitutes a space in php

Tags: php

I am user a header function to redirect a page. Space is not allowed before the header function in php. I have some functions on the page and I was wonder if what is in between a function is considered white space.

will I have to do this:

```
function nil(){
statement
}
```

or can I do this:

```
function nil(){

Is this considered space?

statement

is this considered space?


}
```

Comment: unless you are doing an echo '<space>' it is not considered as white space.

Answer (score 1):

those are not considered spaces to worry about. You just need to worry about spaces that are actually sent to the browser (or any other actual output sent to the browser).  The php code itself is not actually sent to the browser.  Only stuff that php may send (e.g. using `echo`) or if you break out of php, or send other headers with `header()`, etc..

```
=== beginning of file === 
                                <-- whitespace
                                <-- whitespace
                                <-- whitespace
<?php                           <-- not whitespace
  for     ($c    =0;            <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
$c<10;                          <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
$c++                            <-- not whitespace
)                               <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
      {                         <-- not whitespace
        ?>                      <-- not whitespace (but there could be trailing whitespace)
  <p>                           <-- whitespace/output
<?php                           <-- not whitespace
  echo $c;                      <-- not whitespace. HOWEVER, you ARE outputting something
?>                              <-- not whitespace (but there could be trailing whitespace)
  </p>                          <-- whitespace/output
   <?php                        <-- there is leading whitespace
  if ($c==20)                   <-- not whitespace
                                <-- not whitespace
    {                           <-- not whitespace
 echo 'twenty!';                <-- not whitespace. also, even though an echo would output, the condition would never be true so it is never actually output
   }                            <-- not whitespace
}                               <-- not whitespace
      header(                   <-- not whitespace
'Content-type: application/pdf' <-- not whitespace
);                              <-- not whitespace. anything after this doesn't matter because header is sent
      ?> hello!                 <-- output. doesn't matter, header already sent
      <div>                     <-- output. doesn't matter, header already sent
   blah                         <-- output. doesn't matter, header already sent
          </div>                <-- output. doesn't matter, header already sent
=== end of file ===
```

Okay so in reality, hopefully you won't write your code this ugly, but this should demonstrate the points. Although there is in fact a lot of whitespace, the point is that it's whitespace within the context of php code being executed. That whitespace doesn't get sent to the browser, because php code isn't sent to the browser. So even though you see a lot of whitespace in the code, I only labeled the stuff that actually gets sent to the browser.  But the overall point here is that it's not just whitespace - it's *anything* sent to the browser before the header.

Header information must come before *any* other output. If your code outputs anything before headers are sent, and then you try to send headers (this also includes attempting to start a session or write a cookie), php will give you a warning.  You may not even see it, depending on your error level settings. php will not directly crash, since it doesn't really care about headers - that's something for the browser to sort out.  But if you attempt to send a header after output has been sent, the browser will ignore it. And *indirectly* your php script may fail, if it's depending on certain things (e.g. if you are attempting to start a session and read session vars, but you output something before a `session_start()` call).

Comment: So can this work: $variabele space here $variable space here header("Location:http://www.example.com"); what is considered output space? Please give me an example

Comment: So if you have some if statements where the header will execute if a particular condition is meant, php will ignore white space in the other conditions if those conditions are not met?

Comment: @Iamcoder yes. I think you're overthinking things. Anything that is php code to be executed is not considered whitespace.  Anything that is actually sent to the browser during execution, is.

Comment: @Iamcoder basically ask yourself this: "is this going to be something sent to my browser, that I will "see" when i look at the web page or do a rightclick > viewsource on the page?" If the answer is yes, then the header must come before it.

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrapped within `<?php` and `?>` is not sent to the browser, but instead is sent to the PHP parser + interpreter. All whitespaces get ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 0):

The output before a header is data sent, not typed into the file. So..

invalid

```
<?php
    function blah() {
        echo "some output";
    }
    blah();
    header(...);
?>
```

valid

```
<?php
    function blah() {
        echo "some output";
    }
    header(...);
    blah();
?>
```

also invalid

```
<?php
    $var1 = "zzz";
?>

<?php
    header(...);
```

This is invalid because the space between the two PHP blocks outputs HTML before the header is called.

If that last one doesn't make sense I can clarify.